# loading module 8812au fails

Tags: kernel-modules

Why is this not loading my module?

```
y9@y9-aspire:~$ sudo modprobe 8812au.ko
[sudo] password for yannik: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic
y9@y9-aspire:~$ cd /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/
y9@y9-aspire:/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic$ ls
8812au.ko  misc               modules.builtin.bin  modules.order        updates
build      modules.alias      modules.dep          modules.softdep      vdso
initrd     modules.alias.bin  modules.dep.bin      modules.symbols
kernel     modules.builtin    modules.devname      modules.symbols.bin
```

It's in the directory, yet it's saying the module isn't found...

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is not a broken symlink?

Comment: It may need to be in a subdirectory under .../4.13.0-26-generic

Comment: .../kernel/drivers/net/wireless